# A measure theory question

Tags: measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, fa.functional-analysis

Here's an interesting problem one can formulate for a student. This problem arises when considering special ergodic theorems:

*On a finite dimensional manifold $M$ with a Lebesgue measure $\mu$, does every measure zero set equal a countable union of the sets of less than full Hausdorff dimension*?

For a diffeomorphism $f$ of $M$ and a continuous function $\varphi$ on $M$, define $$\overline \varphi = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_0^{n-1} \varphi \circ f^k(x).$$ Then the Birkhoff theorem asserts that for almost all $x$,  $\overline \varphi \rightarrow \int_M \varphi, n \rightarrow \infty$. But consider the set $K_{\alpha}$ of $x$ where $$\alpha \leq |\overline \varphi - \int \varphi|.$$
So Birkhoff says $\mu(K_\alpha)=0$, but what about the Hausdorff dimension of $\mu(K_\alpha)=0$?  For some diffeomorphisms, for example hyperbolic maps,
it was proven that $\dim_H K_\alpha < \dim X$. 
That fact gives a rise to my question. I expect a negative answer, but I can not find a counterexample.

Comment: It's not clear what "decomposed" means. Do you mean that expressing the set of measure zero as union of the sets of a Hausdorff dimension less than full? Then, do you want to allow "uncountable" union? If so, any set of measure zero is union of points. 

Comment: I mean expresing the set of measure zero as a countable (or less) union of the sets of a Hausdorff dimension less than full. In the remark, $\alpha$ could be taken $\frac{1}{n}$. So I do not accept such an easy solution. I hope, now it's more precise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider a function $h$ defined on the unit interval $[0,1]$ which is monotone 
nondecreasing and for which $h(0)=0$, $h$ continuous at $0$. We may define 
a Hausdorff measure $H_h$ associated to $h$ (see Donoghue, Distributions and Fourier 
Transforms Academic Press New York 1969  p. 30--35, or  C. A. Rogers, Hausdorff Measures,
Cambridge University Press, 1970). When $h(x)=x^\alpha$ you get the ordinary 
Hausdorff measures $H_\alpha$.  Consider also $f(x)=x\log(e/x)$.

Then a set $A\subset{\bf R}$ with  $0<  H_f(A)<1$  has measure of Lebesgue $0$ but it is not 
union of a numerable set $A=\bigcup A_n$  with  $H_{\alpha_n}(A_n)=0$ and 
$0<\alpha_n<1$, because this implies  $H_f(A_n)=0$ and so $H_f(A)=0$.

As similar construction applies to each ${\bf R}^n$.

Comment: Perhaps I must explain that the existence of $A\subset{\bf R}$
with $0<H_f(A)<1$  is 
well known and due to Dvoretzky:
Dvoretzky, A.
A note on Hausdorff dimension functions.
Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 44, (1948). 13–16. 

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, as far as I understand, for $\mathbb{R}^n$ we have to consider $f_n(x)=x^n \log (e/x)$ and everything will work as it has to. And the number e in the definition of f doesn't value much - we can take any positive number we want. 

Comment: Yes, the constant $e$ is only to make $x \log(e/x)$  monotone on $[0,1]$. In fact $H_f = H_g$ if  $f$ and $g$ coincide on an interval
$[0,\varepsilon]$, therefore there is some liberty in choosing $f$.